# How to get cash in Europe (ATM cards and taking cash) coming from United States

Tags: money, exchange, atms

Can someone recommend a good ATM card to obtain for an American going to Europe.  Specifically, I'm going to England/Wales if that makes a difference.

To give back, I mention that I have a Amazon Prime Rewards Visa that is extremely good for credit card transactions in Europe (no fees!).  I used it exclusively in France.  However, I feel it's sometimes necessary to get cash and the ATM cards I have charge something like $10 minimum + 3-5% transaction fee PLUS whatever the local ATM machine charges.  The Amazon card also charges considerable fees if used as a debit card at an ATM.

I do plan to take some cash with me, but I don't like to carry huge amounts.  As an aside, if someone has recommendations how to get British pounds before the trip, please let me know also.  I currently use Chase Bank.

Many thanks!
Dave

Comment: Wow, these are insane fees. Happy not to live in the US.  P.S.: AFAIK as I know ATMs in Europe (the places I can think of) don't charge fees on VISA transactions beyond what the card issuer charges.

Comment: Chase's ATM fees are such a rip off. Have you looked into opening an account at a local credit union? Mine has no foreign ATM fees and only a 1% foreign transaction fee.

Comment: I use mostly citibank cards, and have never been charged by them for using a non-citi ATM. Most travel credit cards (eg airline or hotel co-branded) will not have any of that BS.

Answer (score 1):

Like jdouglas's comment, my local credit union in the US gives me an ATM card that has no ATM fee within the US and a 1% fee for ATMs outside the US. (I checked afterwards and calculated that there's no hidden fee baked into the exchange rate.) In Europe I found some ATMs with no fees, so I only paid 1% total fees. Hope you can find the same!